# $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_1^n \frac{(\log k)^4}{ k^2}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the  series converge?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_1^n \dfrac{(\log k)^4}{  k^2}$$

Comment: Dear Robinson, what have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried any convergence tests?

Comment: Do you know for any $\alpha>0$, one has $\log n<n^\alpha$ for sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Comment: See here for the [general theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357954/does-the-following-series-converge) that you can use.

Comment: hints: (i) $\ln k$ grows more slowly than any power of $k$ as $k \to \infty$, (ii) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges for any $p > 1$ by the Integral Test.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)^4}{x^2}dx = \frac{-24-24 \ln(x) -12 \ln(x)^2-4 \ln(x)^3 -\ln(x)^4}{x}|_1^{\infty}=24$. Since this integral converges your series converges by the integral test.