# Integral test for convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, convergence-divergence

Show that 
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac1{n \log n(\log \log n)^p}$$
converges if and only if $ p > 1$.

I know the hint for this: we have to use integral test so we know that the sum of $f(n)$ converges $\iff$  integral of $f(x)$ converges.

Anyone know how exactly to do this?

Comment: In the integral, substitute: $u=\log(\log x)$.

Comment: See [main theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357954/does-the-following-series-converge) and to evaluate the integral use substitution $u=\ln(\ln(x))$ and the problem will fall apart.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\int\limits_3^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x\log x(\log\log x)^p}
=\int\limits_3^{+\infty}\frac{d(\log x)}{\log x(\log\log x)^p}
=\int\limits_3^{+\infty}\frac{d(\log\log x)}{(\log\log x)^p}
=\frac{(\log\log x)^{-p-1}}{-p-1}\Biggl|_3^{+\infty}
=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\frac{(\log\log x)^{-p-1}}{-p-1}-\frac{(\log\log 3)^{-p-1}}{-p-1}=+\infty
$$
Hence by integral test the series
$$
\sum\limits_{n=3}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n\log n(\log\log n)^p}
$$
diverges

Comment: sorry, can you explain how you get that?

Comment: Is it clear that $d(\log x)=\frac{dx}{x}$ ?

Comment: i think u mean f(x) = ln x, f'(x) = 1/x ..?

Comment: I think my biggest problem here is i dont know how to integrate 1/x log x (log log x)^p

Comment: @yes, since you correctly understod what I menat. In fact my hint is a way of integration - just put $\int$ sign in front of each fraction

Comment: but how do i integrate for (log log x)^p ?

Comment: make change of variables $u=\log\log x$. Which expression will yo get then?

Comment: i know ∫ 1/x ln x dx = ln(ln x) but then how to combine with the variables u = log log x ?

Comment: @Risa answer my last question, otherwise I will not help you

Comment: i'm guessing its log x. sorry, i'm not very confident in this topic

Comment: No, after change $u=\log\log x$ you will get $\int du/u^p$. Is it clear?

Comment: oh! yes i got that now. so ∫ 1/x log x (log log x)^p is it [ln (ln x)]*[u^(-p-1)]/[-p-1]?

Comment: No it is $\frac{u^{-p-1}}{-p-1}$ where $u=\log\log x$

Comment: yeah i got that too, but i meant after getting that, now as a whole i got [ln(ln x)u^(-p-1)]/[-p-1]. do i have to substitute u = log log x back into this expression?

Comment: No this is wrong, why did you want to multiply by $\log\log x$? It is redundat here

Comment: cause that ln(ln x) is the integral of 1/x ln x. As I need to integrate the function then I can find the limit and then converges..

Comment: @Risa you need to repeat integrals from the very begining... I gave up. Here is a complete solution $$\int\frac{dx}{x\log x(\log\log x)^p}=\int\frac{d(\log x)}{\log x(\log\log x)^p}=\int\frac{d(\log\log x)}{(\log\log x)^p}=\int \frac{du}{^p}=\frac{u^{-p-1}}{-p-1}=\frac{(\log\log x)^{-p-1}}{-p-1}$$

Comment: thanks for the effort thou i still dont understand. :(

Comment: @Risa, see my edits

Comment: @Risa see my ans. i hope u understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using Cauchy condensation test,

For $p=1$,

Here $$a_n=\frac{1}{n\log n \log (\log n)}$$

By Cauchy condensation test $\sum a_n $& $\sum 2^n a_{2^n}$ converges or diverges together,

\begin{align*}
\sum 2^n a_{2^n}&=\sum 2^n \frac{1}{2^n \log {2^n} \log (\log 2^n)}\\ 
                &=\sum \frac{1}{n\log 2 \log (n \log 2)} 
\end{align*}

Since,

$\log 2 < 1$

$n \log 2 < n$

$\displaystyle \frac {1}{n \log 2} > \frac {1}{n}$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\underbrace{n \log 2}_{m} \log\underbrace{(n \log 2)}_{m}} > \frac{1}{n \log n}$

Check the behavior  $\displaystyle \sum \frac{1}{m \log m} $ it is divergent for p=1,

There is one example which you have to solve,

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log n)^p} \ \  \text{if} \ \  p>0 $$

For $P>1$ converges and $P\leq 1$ diverges.

$\displaystyle \therefore \sum 2^n a_{2^n}$ is divergent

$\displaystyle \therefore \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n \log n \log (\log n)} $ is divergent.

I hope you can conclude behavior for $P>1$.