# Is this series convergent? $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\log n)^2}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\log n)^2}{n^2}$

I guess it is convergent, so I apply comparsion test for this.

$\frac{log^2}{n^2} < \frac{n^2}{n^2} = 1$

So it is bounded by 1 and hence it is convergent.

Can I do in this way? It kind of make sense, but I have never deal with constant in this case

Usually we do bounding using another term depend on $n$?

Comment: [Cauchy condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

Comment: See also: [Does $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(\ln n)^2}{n^2}}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/433335) and [Show convergence/divergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{(\ln n)}^{2}}{{n}^{2}} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1247928)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln^k(n) }{n^a}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2901457/convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-lnkn-na)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do that way as Gerry mentioned. However, you know that $\log^2n\leq\sqrt n$ for $n$ big enough and that's why for big $n$ you have $\frac{(\log n)^2}{n^2}\leq \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$. For the latter series do converge.

Comment: You could make a mention why the latter series converges.

Comment: @Vishal: I assume that the OP knows about the convergence properties of $\sum n^p$, true. Nevertheless, for the latter case the integral test can be used.

Comment: Mine looks so elementary among yours, so I preferred to remove that. +1 :-)

Comment: @BabakS.: I see, thanks

Comment: @BabakS. I would personnally do it the way you deleted...You lost an upvote.

Comment: @julien: I saw that I had nothing more than others to say. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do it that way. You have shown that the terms are bounded by $1$, but that's also true of the series $1+1+1+\dots$; does that series converge?

Answer (score 2):

What you did is wrong since you have to compare with the general term of a converging series.

You can try [Cauchy's Condensation Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

$$\frac{2^nn^2\log^22}{2^{2n}}=\log^2\frac{n^2}{2^n}$$

and now it's easy to check that $\,\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{2^n}}\;$ converges (for example, the n-th root test)

Answer (score 2):

Note that, by the [integral test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357954/does-the-following-series-converge)

$$ \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln(x))^2}{x^2}dx = -{\frac { \left( \ln  \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}}{x}}-2\,{\frac {
\ln  \left( x \right) }{x}}-\frac{2}{x}
\Big|_{x=1}^{\infty} =2 . $$

the series converges.

**Main result:** Suppose $f$ is continuous, positive, decreasing function on $[1,\infty)$ and let $a_n=f(n)$. Then

$(a)$ if $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x) dx$ is convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ is convergent.

$(b)$ if $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x) dx$ is divergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ is divergent.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\log n\le n-1$ for all $n$, we get $\frac{1}{4}\log n \le \sqrt[4]{n}-1\le \sqrt[4]{n}$ for all $n$. So
$$\frac{\log^2 n}{n^2}\le \frac{16\sqrt{n}}{n^2}=\frac{16}{n\sqrt{n}}$$
and we know that $\sum \frac{16}{n\sqrt{n}}$ converges. So by comparison test, $\sum \frac{\log^2 n}{n^2}$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle a_n = \frac{\log^2 n}{n^2}$.
Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right) = -2 < -1.$$
The series converges by [Raabe's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test).