# Show convergence/divergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{(\ln n)}^{2}}{{n}^{2}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{(\ln n)}^{2}}{{n}^{2}} $$

Anyone can give hint for this?

Thank you!

Comment: A useful fact for sums involing logs: For any small $\epsilon > 0$ we have $\log n < n^\epsilon$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. Proving this and using comparison with $\sum 1/n^p$ gives the result.

Comment: See also [Does $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(\ln n)^2}{n^2}}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/433335)
and [Is this series convergent? $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\log n)^2}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/406718).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $1+x\le e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, for $x\gt0$,
$$
1+\tfrac14\log(x)=1+\log\left(x^{1/4}\right)\le x^{1/4}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\log(x)\le4x^{1/4}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log(n)^2}{n^2}
&\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{16n^{1/2}}{n^2}\\
&=16\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{3/2}}\\
\end{align}
$$
which converges by comparison to the [$p$-series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#P-series) where $p=\frac32\gt1$.

---

Using the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), we can compute
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log(n)^2}{n^2}
\doteq1.98928023429890102342085868988
$$

Comment: can you show the steps before the first equality(1+0.25log(x)=1+log(x^0.25)<=x^0.25 ? thx! and why you do so~

Comment: @UnusualSkill: $1+\frac14\log(x)=1+\log\left(x^{1/4}\right)$ is just using a basic property of logarithms. $1+\log\left(x^{1/4}\right)\le x^{1/4}$ is just an application of $1+x\le e^x$. I use this inequality since it shows that $\log(x)\le4x^{1/4}$

Comment: k know alrdy. But in the future if I face such question, can I just use x<=e^x since it is also true?

Comment: Sure, $x\lt1+x\le e^x$.

Comment: can I say that this inequality is very useful for comparing function involves e^x and ln x? as I can adjust the value of x in the inequality, like what u did x becomes x^1/4

Comment: You can certainly say that $\log(x)\le nx^{1/n}$.

Comment: thx, you may have a look at my other questions, see whether u can help onot thx!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try with Cauchy's condensation theorem; you will get a series of the form
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{\alpha}}{2^{n\beta}}.
$$
Now, this series converges for any $\beta>0$.

Comment: For the condensation test, you need to multiply each term by $2^n$ as well as substitute $n\mapsto2^n$.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n \frac{(\log 2^n)^2}{(2^n)^2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{2^n} <\infty$. I always use this method when I have a series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^a (\log n) ^b$.

Comment: Okay, then you might want to mention what $\alpha$ and $\beta$ apply to the given problem.

Comment: Well, I wanted to let the OP work with the test and find the $\alpha,\beta$ by himself rather than specifying them from the beginning. I just give hints but not answers when I don't see that the OP has gone too far.

Comment: Fair enough. (Just to prevent confusion, I preface my hints with **Hint:**)

Comment: Alright, will do so from now on :)

Answer (score 1):

Hit : Compare the sum to the integral
$$\int \frac{\ln(x)^2}{x^2}dx=C-\frac{(\ln x)^2+2 \ln(x)+2}{x}$$
wich tends to a constant $C$ for $x$ tending to infinity. (Of course, $C$ is not the limit of the sum). I let you construct the full answer.

For information only : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{(\ln n)}^{2}}{{n}^{2}}=\zeta''(2) $ , second derivative of the Riemann zeta function. This is not necessary to be known, to answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

*With asymptotic analysis:*

It is easy to check:
$$\frac{\log^2 n}{n^2}=o\biggl(\frac1{n^{3/2}}\biggr)$$
hence it converges.

Indeed the little-oh assertion means that
$$n^{3/2}\frac{\log^2 n}{n^2}=\frac{\log^2x}{n^{1/2}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.$$

*Note:*
This series is but a particular case of a *Bertrand's series* : $\,u_n=\dfrac1{n^{\alpha}\log^{\beta}n}\enspace\alpha,\beta\in\mathbf R$, hich converges if $\alpha>1$ or if ($\alpha=1$  a $\beta>1$).

Comment: The estimate you have is true, but it is not clear how you got it. "asymptotic analysis" doesn't really say much.

Comment: The interest of asymptotic analysis is precisely it removes the superfluous, keeping only what's essential.;For some details on how I got it, look at my updated answer.

Comment: Since they asked this question, I doubt if the OP knew that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)^2}{n^{1/2}}=0$. This probably requires some justification.

Comment: I don't know. Here in France,$\, \lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\log^ \alpha x}{x^ \beta}=0\enspace\alpha,\beta>0$ is more or less in the curriculum of high school, as an immediate corollary of the basic  case $\,\alpha=\beta=1$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's nowhere exciting as other answers, but since $\frac{\log^2 x}{x^2}$ is monotone decreasing for $x>1$, you can compare it to the integral
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{1}^{n}\frac{\log ^2 x dx}{x^2}
$$
and IBP twice, both times with $\int f' = \int \frac{dx}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you like an overkill, the Kummer's Fourier series for the $\log\Gamma$ function gives:

> $$\log\Gamma(t) = \frac{1}{2}\,\log\left(\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi t)}\right)+(\gamma+\log(2\pi))\left(\frac{1}{2}-t\right)+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log n}{n}\,\sin(2\pi n t) $$

hence your series is converging by Parseval's theorem, since both
$$ \log\Gamma(t),\quad \log\left(\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi t)}\right),\quad \left(\frac{1}{2}-t\right) $$
belong to $L^2(0,1)$. Namely:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \log^2\left(\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi t)}\right)\,dt = \frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{1}{4}\,\log^2(4\pi^2). $$
Moreover:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log^2 n}{n^2}=\zeta''(2),$$
where the $\zeta(s)$ function is analytic over $\text{Re}(s)>1$.

Answer (score 0):

As usual for this type of series, you should compare to an integral. In this case, to $\int \frac{\log^2 x}{x^2} dx$. This primitive has a simple expression through usual functions, and by carefully writing your series-integral comparison you should be able to prove easily that this does converge.

(Or, but this is more specific, you could also directly use that $(log x)^2/x^2 = O(1/x^{1+\varepsilon})$).