# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln^k(n) }{n^a}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Show when $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln^k(n) }{n^a}$ is convergent.

Tried using convergence tests. I tried to calculate 
$$\lim: \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{\ln^k(n) }{n^a}}{\frac{1}{n^a}}$$
but that doesn't help me.
Need some advises, thanks

Comment: You should clarify the range for $a$ and $k$, otherwise we need to consider some cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha \ln^\beta (n)} $ for nonnegative $\alpha$ and $\beta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267697/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-alpha-ln-beta-n-for)

Comment: @MaorRocky Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

We should declare the range for $a$ and $k$, otherwise we need to consider the following cases:

- For $a>1$ take $b=\frac{1+a}2$ and apply limit comparison test with
  $\sum \frac1{n^b}$.
- For $0\le a<1$ and $k\ge0$ use comparison test with $\sum
     \frac1{n^a}$.
- For $0\le a<1$ and $k<0$ refer to Cauchy condensation test.
- For $a<0$ we have that $a_n \not \to 0$.

Note also that when $k<0$ we need to start from $n=2$ in order to have a well defined expression.

Comment: Concrete and satisfying+

Comment: @ResidentDementor Thanks for your kind appreciation!Maybe I should add that for the case $k<0$ we need to start from $n=2$. Bye!