# Is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sin\frac{\log^{4}k}{1+tk^{3}}$ absolutely convergent for each $t>0?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

> Is the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sin\frac{\log^{4}k}{1+tk^{3}}$ absolutely convergent for each $t\in \left(0,\infty\right)$? Justify your answer.

What I did was the original series is less than $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log^{4}k}{1+tk^{3}}$. I do not know which test I should apply for the convergence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln^k(n) }{n^a}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2901457) (found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Clog%5E%7B4%7Dk%7D%7Bk%5E%7B3%7D%7D%24&p=2))