# Need to clarify that this series diverges

Tags: divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{\log^2 n}$$ diverges by using integral test.

Is this true?

Comment: Here is the [main result](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357954/does-the-following-series-converge) for integral test.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the [main result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357954/does-the-following-series-converge), the integral test goes like this, pick up the function $f(x)= \frac{1}{\ln(x)^2} $ and see this

$$ \int_{3}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\ln(x)^2} =  \int_{\ln(3)}^{\infty}\frac{e^y}{y^2}dy, $$

where the last integral is a divegent integral, since $\lim_{y\to \infty}\frac{e^y}{y^2}=\infty$.

**Note:** We used the change of variables $y=\ln(x)$ in the above integral.

Answer (score 1):

For $n\ge 1$, $\ln(n)^2<n$ so this series diverges by comparison to $\sum 1/n$.

Comment: I agree, but OP said "using integral test".

Comment: Oh, I couldn't really understand that from the posed question