# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln n }{\sqrt{n^3-n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Why the following series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln n }{\sqrt{n^3-n+1}}$$

converges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that by L'Hospital's Rule, or other methods,$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log n}{n^{1/4}}=0$. So if $n$ is large enough, $\log n \lt n^{1/4}$.

Note also that $n^3-n+1\gt n^3/4$. Thus if $n$ is large enough, then
$$\frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n^3-n+1}}\lt \frac{2}{n^{5/4}}.$$
It follows by Comparison that our series converges.

Answer (score 0):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425368/does-sum-n-1-infty-frac-lnnn22-converge/427377#427377). Note that, you can compare as

$$ \frac{\ln n }{\sqrt{n^3-n+1}} \sim \frac{\ln n }{\sqrt{n^3}},$$

and the series

$$ \sum_{n}\frac{\ln n }{\sqrt{n^3}} $$

converges by [integral test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357954/does-the-following-series-converge).

Comment: Why is $1/\sqrt{n^3 - n +1} \approx 1/\sqrt{n^3}$?

Comment: @sidht $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3-n+1}} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3(1-1/n^2 +1/n^3)}} $$

Comment: @ShuhaoCao: Thanks for answering him.