# Test for convergence of positive term series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> $$\frac{2}{1^p}\ + \frac{3}{2^p}\ + \frac{4}{3^p}\ +\ldots\,.$$

I can see that the $nth$ term is $\frac{n+1}{n^p}$

How do I test for its convergence?

Comment: Should the third term be $\frac{4}{3^p}$?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Edited it. :)

Comment: Check the [integral test](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357954/does-the-following-series-converge).

Comment: Thanks but the intergral test is not included within my syllabus I'm afraid. I used the p-series test. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n+1}{n^p} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\dfrac{n}{n^p}+\dfrac{1}{n^p}\right] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\dfrac{1}{n^{p-1}}+\dfrac{1}{n^p}\right]$. Now apply the $p$-test.

Comment: I don't know what the p is here, how will I apply the p-series test?

Comment: Convergence will depend on the value of $p$. So your answer will be something like "The series converges for [conditions on $p$] and diverges for [opposite conditions on $p$]".

Comment: Ok then! Divergent for $p<=2$ and convergent for $p>2$