# How to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^k}$ converges for all integer $k > 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n^k}$$
converges for all integer $k > 1$?

I know that comparison test would suffice to show that, but don't know how to start.

Comment: Note that it suffices to establish convergence for $k=2$. Then you can use the comparison test to conclude the same for larger $k$. So that reduces the number of cases you have to consider from countably infinite to one. :-)

Comment: I guess that 12 minutes are too short a time span to have the opportunity to note that the title should be heavily edited, if one is to follow the usual conventions of mathematical language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You can use the [integral test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357954/does-the-following-series-converge).

Answer (score 5):

Compare $\frac{1}{n^2}$ with $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ ($n \ge 2$).

The second of these decomposes into partial fractions and the infinite sum can be easily computed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: Suppose $a_n\geq a_{n+1}\geq 0 \; \forall\; n\;\in\mathbb{N} $. Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}2^ma_{2^m}$ converges.

Here we get $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}2^m\frac{1}{2^{mk}}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}2^{(1-k)m}$. Note that this ia a geometric series with commom ratio $2^{1-k}$. Since $k>1$, $2^{1-k}<1$.  Thus the series $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}2^m\frac{1}{2^mk}$ converges. Hence the given series convergent.

Comment: Note: this very much requires the sequence to be monotone!

Comment: ya, monotone is needed, i edited. Thank you.